# Create Global Mapper script

Tags: wms, ecw, global-mapper

I want create a GlobalMapper script that allows to export from a WMS:
http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/WMS_v1.3/raster/ortofoto_colore_12.map
to a ECW after defining the coordinates.

For example: Bari /Est 17 04.16 / Sud 41 04.23 / West 17 47.92 / Nord 41 08.96

Answer (score 2):

Global Mapper is able to export WMS to ECW (verified).

It sounds like you are needing to export imagery. You will have to determine the relationship between your WMS input and ECW export limitation. Global Mapper is limited in what extent and size can be exported to ECW so you will have to determine the maximum scale at which you export your output.

Once you test and verify the radius/extent you can export I would try setting up a script that does the following:

**IMPORT_WMS**
 - Add Server URL
 - LAT_LON_BOUNDS - specifies the bounds to import in latitude/longitude degrees.

**EXPORT_RASTER**
 - FILENAME - full path to file to save the data to
 - TYPE- Specify ECW

Once you are able to get a sample script working you could set up some sort of loop so that it does an export for each input coordinate.

Hopefully, this gets you started. See the following links for more information:

http://data.bluemarblegeo.com/downloads/global-mapper/ScriptReference_16.1.html#cmd_import_wms

http://data.bluemarblegeo.com/downloads/global-mapper/ScriptReference_16.1.html#cmd_export_raster